# Visual Studio Code: The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a python script which I open up in visual studio code. When I first open Visual Studio Code, the following appears in the terminal where it tries to run it under the project folder location.

```
PS C:\Users\foo\Github-int\project> conda activate spyder-env

conda activate spyder-env
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate spyder-env
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It then *automatically* proceeds to the below which works but provides no highlighting of error messages and when the code fails, no problems or warnings appear in the problems pane in the IDE.

`PS C:\Users\foo\Github\project> & C:/Users/foo/Miniconda3/envs/spyder-env/python.exe.`

I have checked my environmental variables and can see from the `Path` that conda is there under the `C:\Users\foo\Miniconda3`. However this is the user variables, not the system variables.

I opened the normal command prompt and tried it with the same error

```
C:\>conda activate
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However if i open the anaconda prompt it seems to work fine

```
(base) C:\>conda activate spyder-env

(spyder-env) C:\>
```

Can anyone help me trouble shoot?

Comment: Most likely you are missing path to conda executable in PATH environment variable.

Comment: Yes, it seems i needed to add the folder where the conda.exe was in the systems variable. It still does not appear to show warnings or errors in different colour but i shall play around with it some more before opening a new question. Thank you very much @matszwecja